Unity level Creation

Can someone help me do this level in unity2d  with canvas
because I've tryied multiple ways nothing worked.
This code is a way I found here to draw a line from a point to another in unity 2d canvas, but when I try doing it to multiple objects it doesn't work
if someone can help me to do it because I've spent more than 4 days on it  and still not able to do it.
I just need a guidnesse to make it or someone willing to help with it
thanks,
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SimpleLineUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image lineImage;
    [SerializeField] private float thickness = 5;
    [SerializeField] private Color color = Color.black;

    public float Length => length;

    private Vector2 startPoint;
    private Vector2 targetPoint;
    private float length;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lineImage.color = color;

        ResetLine();
    }

    public void SetStartPoint(Vector2 position, bool update = true)
    {
        startPoint = position;

        if (update)
            UpdateLine();
    }
    public void SetTargetPoint(Vector2 position, bool update = true)
    {
        targetPoint = position;

        if (update)
            UpdateLine();
    }
    public void SetThickness(float thickness)
    {
        if (this.thickness != thickness)
        {
            this.thickness = thickness;
            lineImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(length, thickness);
        }
    }
    public void SetColor(Color color)
    {
        if (this.color != color)
        {
            this.color = color;
            lineImage.color = color;
        }
    }
    public void ResetLine()
    {
        length = 0;
        SetStartPoint(Vector2.zero, false);
        SetTargetPoint(Vector2.zero, false);
        lineImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private void UpdateLine()
    {
        var direction = targetPoint - startPoint;
        var rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        length = direction.magnitude;

        lineImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = startPoint;

        lineImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(length, thickness);

        lineImage.rectTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotationAngle);
    }
}

the code use image instead of of line render to make it appear on a canvas

you have 1 line image, it can only be in 1 place at a time. you surely need to instantiate copies of the line...

can you help me created because it's not working for me

I would recommend looking at the UILineRenderer, it does what you want but without all of the extra code, give it 2 points and a line is generated.
https://unity-ui-extensions.github.io/Controls/UILineRenderer.html

@SalmanMoussa Create a prefab of the image with this script attached, configured as shown in the original question.  When you want to create a new line, instantiate the prefab.  You will need 1 instance for each line you want to draw.
